# Use of List.Find in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, list, find

I have two columns. One column contains string values and another column contains decimal values. I want to select the decimal value by selecting the string value.

```
string          decimal
Jewel           10
Hasan           20
```

How do I select Jewel so it will return 10?

Comment: Is it a `List` or what? How do you store your columns?

Comment: Dim DisputeList As List(Of InvoiceSOA) = db.GetList(Of InvoiceSOA)("OraclePackage", params)

Comment: What is `InvoiceSOA`? Please, update your question

Comment: its a entity which contains column name

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim selectedValues As List(Of InvoiceSOA)
selectedValues = DisputeList.FindAll(Function(p) p.ColumnName = "Jewel")
```

Or, if you need the first occurence of "Jewel" use this:

```
Dim selectedValue As InvoiceSOA
selectedValue = DisputeList.Find(Function(p) p.ColumnName = "Jewel")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim selectedValue As InvoiceSOA = DisputeList.Find(Function(p) 
        if p.ColumnName = "Jewel" then
            return true
        end if
    end function)
```

Answer (score 0):

The Enum functionality is the right way to use for this question.

Example:

```
Public Enum Ornaments
    Neclace = 10
    Bangle = 20
    TieClip = 30
End Enum
```

How to use this Enum

```
Dim SelectedOrnament As Ornaments = Ornaments.Bangle

Select Case SelectedOrnament

    Case Ornaments.Neclace
        MsgBox("Your ornament is: " & Ornaments.Neclace)

    Case Ornaments.Bangle
        MsgBox("Your ornament is: " & Ornaments.Bangle)

    Case Ornaments.TieClip
        MsgBox("Your ornament is: " & Ornaments.TieClip)

    Case Else
        MsgBox("I could not find your ornament. Sorry")

End Select
```

Comment: Do Enum indexes allow Decimal/Double values?